# Show two Line in the same Chart in Reporting Services

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts

I want to build a report with ReportingServices.
So I want to insert in this report a Line Chart. I want to have this result:

[image]

I want to have in the same chart, two Line. The First line show the result from WC-1 to WC-4 and the second Line show the result from Monday to Sunday.

I had thought to create two dataset but it's impossible to insert more dataset to unique chart. This is my query:

```
DECLARE @TemporaryTable TABLE 
                        (
                        Day NVARCHAR(100),
                        Value DECIMAL(12,5)
                        )

-- Get PO start and end time and the linkupID
DECLARE @DATA_START AS DATETIME
DECLARE @DATA_END AS DATETIME
DECLARE @MACHINE AS NVARCHAR(100)


DECLARE @Date as DATETIME
SET @Date = '2014-10-31'
DECLARE @ProductionLine AS NVARCHAR(100)
SET @ProductionLine = 'COMBINER001'


--THE USER SELECT A DATE, I SET THE DATA IN THE FIRST DAY OF WEEK
SET @DATA_START = dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, @Date), 0);
--THE USER SELECT A DATE, I SET THE DATA IN THE LAST DAY OF WEEK
SET @DATA_END =DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, @DATA_START), 6 + 7)
SET @MACHINE= @ProductionLine


-- Collect downtimes
INSERT INTO @TemporaryTable (Day,Value) VALUES('KP-4',12),('KP-3',13),('KP-2',44),('KP-1',15)
INSERT INTO @TemporaryTable (Day,Value)
SELECT 
    datename(dw,mc.Data) as Date,
    k.Value
FROM
    Machine_Counter mc INNER JOIN 
    KPI_Value k ON (mc.Data = k.Data AND mc.Machine = k.Machine) 
WHERE 
    mc.CounterType = 1 AND 
    mc.Machine LIKE @MACHINE AND
    k.KPI = 3 AND
    mc.Data BETWEEN @DATA_START AND @DATA_END
ORDER BY mc.Data

SELECT Day,Value FROM @TemporaryTable
```